# Current mirror not depending on power supply (BANDGAP design)

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, circuit-design, voltage-reference, reference

is there any topology that allows a current to stay constant on a current mirror when the power supply of the transistor is varied?

I simulated a bandgap and the PTAT varies a lot when I the power supply is varied. Especially at -40 degrees.
Instead of the direct output I used also a current mirror (2 pmos transistors) that is driven by the output of the opamp to get a higher current to be able to drive the resistive output.

The green selected curve is the derivative for the lowest voltage: 1.62V.

Is is possible to improve the linearity of the ptat with respect to power supply sweep?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you learned about PTAT and CTAT? and about using circuits to produce selected ratios of each, and summing them, to produce a near-zero change with temperature? As part of the design, an internal voltage regulator can  be used. And you can make the current-mirrors very long channel (if FET), for improved PSRR.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf  what I calculated works for some voltages, but -40 degrees seems to be a problem as you can see in the picture the derivative of the -40 curve is very steep

Comment: So obviously the circuit doesn't work as intended at -40 C. **So find the root cause**. Do a DC operating point sim at -40 C and check that all the DC voltages are OK. Are the currents OK? Is the mirror still working? Use Annotate DC node voltages to show the DC voltages. Use annotate DC operating point to show the currents.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  the current mirror is working -the currents are the same on both branches. Is there any current mirror design that is not sensitive to power supply variation?

Comment: Have you studied current mirrors? If you have you would know the most commonly used way to improve the performance of a current mirror. Forget about making the current mirror "not sensitive", all current mirrors will have some current variation due to output voltage variations. The question is, what is good enough?